# Why in that sentence does the word 'her' repeat itself?

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

I'd like to know why the word 'her' is repeated after the word 'pacing'.

She knew how fast she was running, because her trainer was pacing '**her**' on a bicycle.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the verb '*to pace*' is used in the meaning of '*setting/regulating the pace of*' her (running), so it works as a *transitive* verb (meaning 3 here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pace ) with the direct object **her** (as opposed to the first instance of 'her' as a possessive pronoun).